# ClamAV check infected file

Tags: terminal, logs, clamav

I ran `clamscan --bell -r /` and in the end it returned me

> Infected files: 1

now is there any way to check which file is infected (i.e. a log file)?

Answer (score 1):

Add the `-i` option:

```
clamscan -r --bell -i /
```